# How to get Name from Code to display on records on JSP by using Strius2 and Hibernate3 Entity Mapping relationship

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hibernate3

I have two tables `Group(Parent)` and`Type(Child)` and they are mapped by `GroupId`. This is done by Hibernate `@OneToMany` Mapping.

My Issue is When I am displaying records of Type Table in *JSP* it is displaying `TypeName` & `GroupId` because I am using `TypeEntity` Class to to this,but I want to display `TypeName` and `GroupName` not the `GroupId`.

As Simple as I want .like: `SELECT A.TYPE_NAME, B.GROUP_NAME FROM TYPE A, GROUP B WHERE A.GROUP_ID = B.GROUP_ID;`

Currently I am using:

```
 List<UserTypeEntity> typeList = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userActive", 
"Y").ignoreCase()).addOrder(Property.forName("userTypeName").asc()).list();
```

Just help on this how can I approch using *hibernate3*

My TypeEntity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_TYPE_MSTR")
public class UserTypeEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_TYPE_ID")
    private int userTypeId;

    @Column(name="USER_TYPE")
    private String userTypeName;

    @Column(name="USER_TYPE_DESC")
    private String userTypeDesc;

//  @ManyToOne
    @Column(name="USER_GRP_ID")
    private int userGroupId;

          ..... Setter Getters....
}
```

And My GroupEntity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_GROUP_MSTR")
public class UserGroupEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_GRP_ID")
    private int userGroupId;

    @Column(name="USER_GRP")
    private String userGroupName;

    @Column(name="USER_GRP_DESC")
    private String userGroupDesc;


    @Column(name="ACTIVE")
    private String userActive;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable( name                ="USER_GROUP_TYPE", 
                joinColumns         = {@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_GRP_ID")},
                inverseJoinColumns  = {@JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID",  referencedColumnName="USER_TYPE_ID")}
    )
    private Set<UserTypeEntity> userTypeEntities;

    /**
     * @return the userTypeEntities
     */
    public Set<UserTypeEntity> getUserTypeEntities() {
        return userTypeEntities;
    }

    /**
     * @param userTypeEntities the userTypeEntities to set
     */
    public void setUserTypeEntities(Set<UserTypeEntity> userTypeEntities) {
        this.userTypeEntities = userTypeEntities;
    }
          .... Getters & Setters ....
}
```

My DAO Class:

```
public class UserTypeDAO {
private List<UserTypeEntity> typeList = null;
private Criteria criteria;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<UserTypeEntity> getUserTypes() throws HibernateException{
        log.info("...In UserTypeDAO.getUserTypes...");
        try {
            criteria = ConnectionFactory.getSessionfactory().openSession().createCriteria(UserTypeEntity.class);
            typeList = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userActive", "Y").ignoreCase()).addOrder(Property.forName("userTypeName").asc()).list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return typeList;
    }
}
```

My Action Class:

```
public class UserTypeAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable{
private List<UserTypeEntity> typeList;
@SkipValidation
    public String userTypeView() throws Exception{
        try {
            typeList = (List<UserTypeEntity>)UserTypeController.getUserTypes();
            if(typeList.size() > 0){
                setTypeList(typeList);              

                result = SUCCESS;
            }else {
                result = SUCCESS;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And My JSP:

```
<s:if test="%{typeList.size() != 0}">
                <s:iterator value="typeList" var="type">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><s:property value="userTypeName"/></td>
                        <td align="left"><s:property value="userTypeDesc"/></td>
                        <td align="left"><s:property value="userGroupId"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><s:date name="userCreatedDate" format="dd-MMM-yyyy" /></td>
                        <td align="center"><s:date name="userModifiedDate" format="dd-MMM-yyyy" /></td>
                        <td align="center"><b><a href="#" onclick="javascript:userTypeEdit('edit','${userTypeId}','${userTypeName}','${userTypeDesc}','${userGroupId}','${userCreatedDate}','${userModifiedDate}');">Edit</a></b>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><a href="#" onclick="javascript:userTypeDelete('userTypeDelete.action?typeId=${userTypeId}');">Delete</a></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%"><div style="color:red;">No Results found</div></td>
                </tr>
            </s:else>
```

Comment: Show your entities, JSP and full query.

Comment: 1 Better you use view for this.. create view in database. Make new entity whose table and fields mapping will be with the view name. It will be good as you do not have any update or insert on the list. or 2 You can use hql or 3 Instead of creating  only Id you should create object of `UserGroupEntity` in `UserTypeEntity` so annotations are in wronge place. you can then call get method of group name then using the object.

Comment: Thanks Parth, Before I got your solution, I already followed your point no 3 and problem solved... Thanx!!!

Answer (score 0):

I Created in TypeEntity Class

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_GRP_ID")
    private UserGroupEntity userGroupEntity;
```

And in GroupEntity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="userGroupEntity")
    private Set<UserTypeEntity> userTypeEntities;
```

Then in JSP I accessed Like:

```
<td align="left"><s:property value="userGroupEntity.userGroupDesc"/></td>
```

And My Problem got Solved...